# R reactable - update a single row

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to update just a single row in reactable?  In the documentation, there is the ability to update the data set:

https://glin.github.io/reactable/reference/updateReactable.html

However I just want to update a single row of a large table, not the entire data set.